# Capture or assign golang template output to variable

Tags: go, go-templates

Within a template, how can I achieve this?

```
{{$var := template "my-template"}}
```

I just get `"unexpected <template> in operand"`.

Answer (score 19):

There is no "builtin" action for getting the result of a template execution, but you may do it by registering a function which does that.

You can register functions with the [`Template.Funcs()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs) function, you may execute a named template with [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate) and you may use a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) as the target (direct template execution result into a buffer).

Here is a complete example:

```
var t *template.Template

func execTempl(name string) (string, error) {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    err := t.ExecuteTemplate(buf, name, nil)
    return buf.String(), err
}

func main() {
    t = template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "execTempl": execTempl,
    }).Parse(tmpl))
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const tmpl = `{{define "my-template"}}my-template content{{end}}
See result:
{{$var := execTempl "my-template"}}
{{$var}}
`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ccN3Zb8WdM)):

```
See result:

my-template content
```

The `"my-template"` template is executed by the registered function `execTempl()`, and the result is returned as a `string`, which is stored in the `$var` template variable, which then is simply added to the output, but you may use it to pass to other functions if you want to.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I don't have access to the go code that is processing the template: (i'm using consul-template)

Comment: How can I know the buffer is big enough?

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt `bytes.Buffer` increases its capacity on demand, it does not run out of space.

Comment: Yes I assumed that, but did not study its write-method ...