# Go capturing template variables and names

Tags: go, go-templates

I am experimenting with Go's templates.

I am curious: is it possible to do the following: `{{$myVariable := randomStringFunc | saveFunc}}`

Where:
`$myVariable` - randomly chosen variable name
`randomStringFunc` - function that generates random strings
**TRICKY:** `saveFunc` - a function that saves the variable name and its value

I have looked into [capture-or-assign-golang-template-output-to-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164896/capture-or-assign-golang-template-output-to-variable) but I am not sure how and if it can help me achieve my goal.

**EDIT**
In the end I would like to have a mapping between the variable name that is defined in the template and the value that is assigned to it:

`var variableMapping map[string]string`
After template execution the content of `variableMapping` should be something like:

```
{
"$myVariable:"randomString1",
"$anotherVariable":"5",
"$thirdVariableInMyTemplate":"false"
}
```

Comment: If i understand you correctly it seems to me that you can, but best to try it out yourself https://play.golang.org/p/CMSu3-Mo_a. Of course your `saveFunc` can then return either the output from `randomStringFunc` or a new value and that is what will be assigned to `myVariable`.

Comment: Your assumption is almost right. The only thing that is missing is getting hold of the name of the variable.

Comment: Ah sorry, now I understand what you mean... but I don't think that's possible with what the Go template engine is able to do.