# get the value of a go template from inside another template

Tags: go, go-templates

I have two templates T1 and T2. I want to get the output of T1 and do a some extra processing on it inside T2. My question is:

how do I store the output of T1 in a variable inside T2? Is this even possible?

Here's some pseudo-template:

```
{{define "T1"}}
    {{ printf "%s-%s" complex stuff }}
{{end}}
{{define "T2"}}
    {{ $some_var := output_from_template "T1"}}  <<<<<<<<<<<
    {{ etc }}
{{end}}
```

Comment: @Marc: this isn't a duplicate. I'm asking about assignment specifically. Look at the line with all the <<<<<<<< on it

Comment: Fair enough, but @icza found one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164896/capture-or-assign-golang-template-output-to-variable/40170999#40170999

Comment: why not simply call T1 from T2 ? see `template` action https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

Comment: @mh-cbon: there are a multitude of reasons for wanting to store a result in memory before printing it out. Personally I need to pass it to some regex functions that just wont work out with pipes.

Comment: @Marc: cool beans. Please feel free to mark it as a duplicate. I like to keep duplicates around because it makes finding things easier. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin support for storing the result of a template in a template variable, only for the inclusion of the result.

But you can register custom functions with any complex functionality you want. You may register a `GetOutput` function which would execute a template identified by its name, and it could return the result as a `string`, which you can store in a template variable.

Example doing this:

```
func main() {
    t := template.New("")

    t = template.Must(t.Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "GetOutput": func(name string) (string, error) {
            buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
            err := t.ExecuteTemplate(buf, name, nil)
            return buf.String(), err
        },
    }).Parse(src))

    if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "T2", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const src = `
{{define "T1"}}{{ printf "%s-%s" "complex" "stuff" }}{{end}}
{{define "T2"}}
    {{ $t1Out := (GetOutput "T1")}}
    {{ printf "%s-%s" "even-more" $t1Out }}
{{end}}`
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TXIwXMEj6Rw)):

```
    even-more-complex-stuff
```

The `"T1"` template simply outputs `"complex-stuff"`, and the `"T2"` template gets the output of `"T1"`, and concatenates the static text `"even-more-"` and the result of `"T1"`.

The registered `GetOutput` function gets the name of a template to execute, executes it by directing its output to a local buffer, and returns the content of the buffer (along with the optional error of its execution).

**Edit:** I've found an exact duplicate: [Capture or assign golang template output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164896/capture-or-assign-golang-template-output-to-variable/40170999#40170999)