# Inject string template with variable

Tags: go

I was looking at this article:

https://medium.com/@IndianGuru/understanding-go-s-template-package-c5307758fab0

I am wondering how to inject a variable into a string using templating, for example:

```
func getTemplate(v string) string {
    return `CREATE TABLE share_${v} PARTITION OF share FOR VALUES IN (${v});`
}
```

the example in the article writes the output to stdout, but I need to store the result of the template as a variable, anyone know how?

Something like:

```
result := getTemplate("0")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture or assign golang template output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164896/capture-or-assign-golang-template-output-to-variable)

Comment: yeah doing this using golang is pretty r*tarded but I am sure I will figure it out

Comment: This isn't templating, and even if it was, you aren't supposed to do it this way anyway. You need to use prepared statements to construct SQL queries.

Comment: yeah I guess so thanks

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you parameterise identifiers?

Answer (score 0):

Golang templating is motherf*cking bonkers. This should work:

```
func getTableCreationCommands(v string) string {
    return `
      CREATE TABLE share_` + v + ` PARTITION OF share FOR VALUES IN (` + v + `);
      CREATE TABLE nearby_` + v + ` PARTITION OF nearby FOR VALUES IN (` + v + `);
    `
}
```