# Go template post processing: is it possible?

Tags: go, templates, yaml

In my template, I use a sub-template that generates a piece of output.
The template output must be shifted though (because the output is in YAML format).
Is there any possibility to post-process template output?

```
{{ template "subtemplate" | indent 10 }}
```

This `indent 10` is fictional, just to explain what I need.

It is possible (as @icza suggested) to save the output
into a variable and then work with it,
but maybe there is a better, more elegant approach?

```
{{$var := execTempl "subtemplate"}}
{{$var}}
```

Comment: Capture the output of the template in a variable, which you can pass to other functions. See [Capture or assign golang template output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164896/capture-or-assign-golang-template-output-to-variable/40170999#40170999)

Comment: @icz: Yes, I know about it, but maybe there is any more elegant solution?

Comment: You could make the indentation depth a parameter to `execTempl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to `{{ template "subtemplate" | indent 10 }}` is to define a function that parses and executes the `subtemplate` and outputs the result as string.

```golang
var externalTemplates = map[string]*template.Template{
    "subtemplate": template.Must(template.New("subtemplate").Parse(sub_template)),
}

// Executes external template, must be registered with FuncMap in the main template.
func xtemplate(name string) (string, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    if err := externalTemplates[name].ExecuteTemplate(&b, name, nil); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return b.String(), nil
}
```

```golang
t := template.Must(template.New("t").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "xtemplate": xtemplate, // register func
}).Parse(main_template))
```

In the main template you can then use the function like this:

```
{{ xtemplate "subtemplate" | indent 10 }}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/brolOLFT4xL

Comment: Basically it is the same what @icza suggested: `xtemplate` is `execTempl`, right?

Comment: Yes minus the variable part. That's what you didn't like about that approach isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to be sure that I don't miss anything. It is a good approach, anyway better then other ugly alternatives I had before

Comment: @IgorChubin one difference between icza's linked answer and the above is that icza is using a single instance of `*template.Template` while the above answer is using one for main template and a set of "external templates". Because the above registers `xtemplate` only with the main template you cannot use it inside the external templates. So you may actually prefer the single-instance version if you want to be able to call `xtemplate` also from the "external templates". Although nothing stops you from registering `xtemplate` with the externals as well.